# Grails - Change locale behavior to use dash instead of underscore

Tags: grails, web, internationalization, request, locale

I'm writing a Grails application that get's it's locale from a 3rd party like so:

my.app.com?lang=**en-US** since Grails uses **en_US** it throws the exception `Error intercepting locale change: Locale part "en-US" contains invalid characters`

How can I intercept the request prior to PageFragmentCachingFilter, in order to fix the locale code?

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to override the default behavior is to register a [CustomLocaleChangeInterceptor](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6121053/) as a bean in `resources.groovy` as

```
beans = {
    localeChangeInterceptor(your.package.CustomLocaleChangeInterceptor) {
        paramName = "lang"
    }
}
```

**GIST**
The idea is to override the default `localeChangeInterceptor` which is the default interceptor in i18n grails plugin in order to take care of the hyphenated locale string in the request url parameter. Main logic to look at in the custom locale interceptor is:

```
try {
        // choose first if multiple specified
        if (localeParam.getClass().isArray()) {
            localeParam = ((Object[])localeParam)[0]
        }

        //If locale hyphenated, then change to underscore
        if(localeParam.toString()?.contains('-')){
            localeParam = StringUtils.replace(localeParam.toString(), "-", "_")
        }

        def localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request)
        def localeEditor = new LocaleEditor()
        localeEditor.setAsText localeParam.toString()
        localeResolver?.setLocale request, response, (Locale)localeEditor.value
        return true
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add your own Filter in /grails-app/conf, something like:

```
class LocaleFixingFilters {

    def filters = {
        trace(controller:'*', action:'*') {
            before = {
                params.lang = params.lang?.replaceAll('-', '_')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however the filter is called after the error (+1 for the effort) :)

Comment: weird because it did work for me, but maybe it depends on the execution order of all "before" interceptors

Comment: Here is the error I get:"Error intercepting locale change: Locale part "de-DE" contains invalid characters"